# how to count total number of up vote for all post using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

- post table 2 columns: **postid,question**
- answers table 4 columns: **ansid (PK), postid,userid,answer**
- votes table 4 columns:**postid, userid,ansid,upvote**

Total upvote for single post

```
SELECT sum(votes.upvote) as 'totalupvote' FROM `answers` 
            JOIN post on post.postid=answers.postid
            JOIN votes on votes.ansid=answers.ansid
            WHERE post.postid='1'
```

how to count total number of upvotes for all post?

Comment: you want just the entire total as one result, or you want to see individual results for each post, in a list? It's not clear. If the former, then just remove the `WHERE` clause. If the latter, you'll likely need to use `GROUP BY` to group it by the post ID.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks. Please edit the question to make that clear, then. Showing a small amount of sample data, and the expected result (based on the sample data) would also make it _a lot_ easier for people to help you. Meanwhile, you can be researching GROUP BY queries yourself - you might find the answer before anyone replies here.

Comment: SELECT sum(votes.upvote) as 'totalupvote',post.postid,votes.postid FROM `answers` 
            JOIN post on post.postid=answers.postid
            JOIN votes on votes.ansid=answers.ansid
            GROUP by post.postid

Comment: Please use the "edit" button to add new code to your question. And then explain what problem it is giving you. Code does not belong in the comments...thanks. Or, if that is your working solution, then please add it to the "Answers" section - you are allowed to answer your own question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the totals per `postid`:

```
SELECT postid, sum(upvote) as sumupvote 
FROM votes 
GROUP BY postid
```

If you also want the `question` column:

```
select p.postid, p.question, v.sumupvote
from post p inner join (
  SELECT postid, sum(upvote) as sumupvote 
  FROM votes 
  GROUP BY postid
) v on v.postid = p.postid
```

Answer (score 1):

To display total number of upvotes for all post

```
SELECT sum(votes.upvote) as 'totalupvote',post.postid,post.question FROM 
   votes inner JOIN post on post.postid=votes.postid            
        GROUP by post.postid
```

Comment: You don't need to join the table `answers`.